# Выровнять блок по вертикали + не работает скроллбар

Tags: html, css

Народ нужна помощь.

Снизу ссылка на jsfiddle, там код сайта.

Проблема такая: посередине есть блок с сообщениями. Они уже выровняны по низу родительского блока, но скроллбар не работает. Возможно я где-то ошибся ранее.

Подскажите кто знает, как сделать так, чтобы сообщения были снизу центрального блока(как и есть), но чтобы работал скроллбар, если браузер сузить по вертикали.

https://jsfiddle.net/xmnz3z5c/

```
<div class="send-messages">
<div class="message-windows">
<div class="div-bottom-messages">  
<span class="incoming-messages-1">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin sed metus felis. Mauris consequat aliquet sollicitudin.</p>
<a href="#" title="erat-pellentesque-dignissim.pdf"><span class="mini-icon">   </span><span class="added-files">erat-pellentesque-dignissim.pdf</span></a>

</span>
<span class="incoming-messages">
<div class="author-date-data">
<span class="author">Victor Briggs</span>
<span class="chat-date">08/08/14 06:15 PM</span>
</div>
<p>Suspendisse potenti. Nulla facilisi. Vestibulum libero ligula, vestibulum vel velit sit amet, imperdiet laoreet quam. Fusce blandit, metus quis gravida scelerisque, ante ligula bibendum risus, vitae malesuada dolor quam et diam.</p>   
</span>

<span class="delivered-messages">
<div class="author-date-data">
<span class="author">Me</span>
<span class="chat-date">08/08/14 06:15 PM</span>
</div>  
<p>Duis porttitor, massa eget varius faucibus, nunc libero pulvinar justo, at adipiscing purus arcu eu lectus. Cras neque tortor, varius quis ullamcorper sit amet, congue id erat. Duis tincidunt orci sed fringilla bibendum. Nullam vel consectetur odio, ac posuere erat.</p>   
</span>
</div><!--div-bottom-messages-->
</div><!--message-windows-->
</div><!--end send-messages-->
```